# Пропадает текст при применении своего стиля wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно было сделать так, чтобы при наведении на кнопку менялся цвет (с серого на черный, например). Почитав, я понял что это делается через стили.

```
<Style x:Key="BlackThemeButton" TargetType="Button">
    
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Bahnschrift"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2C2D31"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFE5E5EC"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
    
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Но теперь на кнопке не отображается текст. Как сделать так, чтобы он вернулся (и также менял свой цвет при наведении)?

Comment: Ну подумайте логически, вот вы переписали `Template` в который поместили `Border`, супер, а контент где? Напишите в любимом поисковике `wpf button template`, найдете официальную [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates), где можете изучить стандартный шаблон, ну или можете нажать в студии ПКМ в дизайнере по "голой" кнопке, выбрать пункт "Редактировать стиль" - "Создать копию", вам студия любезно создаст весь этот шаблон, ну а там уже вы можете увидеть, что в `Border` лежит и контент (`ContentPresenter`), которого у вас нету.